# How to post slack message as a workspace user using chat.postmessage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I have created a slack bot who is having some interactive buttons. Once a button is clicked I am going to post a direct message to the user who clicked the interactive button. There i need to show the user profile not the bot profie image. for posting message i am using slack api chat. postmessage ().

When i call this method message is posted as the bot user ( it displays the bot user icon ). But i need to post this message as the user who clicks this buttons. i checked as_user: false property to do this thing. But it didnt work? i am using my app auth token for call this method.

```
var url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage";
    var auth_token ='xoxb-518598944980-577890089556-0i753DBbVkigtyuhfbnmfhjn'; //Your Bot's auth token
    var headers = {
       "Authorization": "Bearer " + auth_token,
       "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
    var body = {
        channel: actionJSONPayload.channel.id,
        text: "Your text goes here.",
        as_user: false // Slack user or channel, where you want to send the message
    }
    request.post({
       "url": url,
       "headers": headers,
       "body": JSON.stringify(body)
    }, (err, response, body) => {
       if (err) {
           reject(err);
       }
       console.log("response: ", JSON.stringify(response));
       console.log("body: ",body);
    });
  }
```

So is there any way to generate tokens specifically to the users who interact with the button dynamically and use that token to call this method? Will it solve this issue or is there anyother ways? i have added all related permissions when installing the application like chat:write:user

Comment: Slack API Document Says Set as_user to true and the authenticated user will appear as the author of the message, ignoring any values provided for username, icon_url, and icon_emoji. Posting as the authenticated user requires the client or the more preferred chat:write:user scopes. But doing this thing didnt make any change. Thats why i need to know if token should be changed according to the user.

Comment: Please refer the below link this solved issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376848/get-parameters-from-stripe-page-redirect-url-node-js

Answer (score 2):

If you need to post the reply message as the user who clicked the button you app needs to call the API method with a token from that user to post the message. That is the only way how an app can impersonate a user on Slack.

So to make this work in your workspace you need to ask every user to install your app once and collect their tokens during the Ouath 2.0 installation process for later user.

This approach has some obvious security issues to consider, e.g. your app will get access to each and every message from every user in your workspace.

A workaround is to manually set the username and icon of a message send by your app (by setting `icon_url` and `username` accordingly and `as_user` = `false` when calling [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)). You can retrieve the icon and username from [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info). Messages will still carry the APP tag to mark them as coming from a bot though.

Comment: Yes you are correct i was able to solve this from this solution. thanks